# How to execute the method if a specific item in the tree is selected?

Tags: javafx

Here is my example given below is editable fall-tree.

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane border;
    TreeItem<String> tree;
    TreeView<String> treeView;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        border = new BorderPane();    
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,750,500);        
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    

         tree = new TreeItem<String>("Library");

         TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Module");
         TreeItem<String> item1Child = new TreeItem<String>("MX");
         item1.getChildren().add(item1Child);

         TreeItem<String> item2 = new TreeItem<String>("Unite");
         TreeItem<String> item2Child = new TreeItem<String>("UX");
         item2.getChildren().add(item2Child);        
         item2.setExpanded(true);        
         TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<String>("Translate");
         TreeItem<String> item3Child = new TreeItem<String>("TX");
         item3.getChildren().add(item3Child);

         TreeItem<String> item4 = new TreeItem<String>("Rotate");
         TreeItem<String> item4Child = new TreeItem<String>("Rx");
         item4.getChildren().add(item4Child);

         tree.setExpanded(true);
         tree.getChildren().addAll(item1,item2,item3,item4);
         treeView  = new TreeView<String>(tree);
         treeView.setEditable(true);
         treeView.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());




             VBox vbox =new VBox(2);
             vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
             VBox.setVgrow(treeView, Priority.ALWAYS);
             vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Text("Fall Tree"),treeView);

            HBox hb = new HBox(); 
            VBox rightPane = getrightPane(); 
             hb.setSpacing(20);
             hb.getChildren().addAll(vbox,rightPane);

             border.setCenter(hb);

        }

        private VBox getrightPane() {
            VBox vb = new VBox(30);
            vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));
            HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
            h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X:"), new TextField());

            HBox box = new HBox(20);
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(150,150);
            rect1.setFill(null);
            rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            box.getChildren().addAll(rect1);
            box.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            vb.getChildren().addAll(h1,box);         
            return vb;
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            launch(args);
        }
```

As it can be seen on comment section a listener is applied but its only checking text on branch and leaf text.

My question is how to assign getrightPane() whole as a listener to the only one leaf(as an example let say MX). when applied, other leaf shouldn't show the getrightPane().

Please help me assign getrightPane() as a listener to only one selected leaf/branch.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. "My question is how to assign getrightPane() whole as a listener to the only one leaf(as an example let say MX). when applied, other leaf shouldn't show the getrightPane()." `getRightPane()` is a method, not a listener. Are you saying you only want to execute that method if a specific item in the tree is selected? If so, why not just put an `if` statement in the listener you have?

Comment: @James_D yes, i want to execute that method if a specific item is selected. i tried with this   <br/>                                                                                        
                     if(selectedItem.getChildren().isEmpty()){ <br/>
         System.out.println("its a mehtod");<br/>
       }<br/>
        else{<br/>
          System.out.println("Its a category");<br/>
           }<br/>
   }<br/>
   
  });<br/>

Comment: And what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    VBox rightPane = new VBox();

    treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

                    if (newValue == item1Child) {                           
                        rightPane.getChildren().add(getrightPane());
                    } else {
                        int i = rightPane.getChildren().size();                         
                        if (i > 0) {
                            rightPane.getChildren().remove(0);
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do, for example:

```
treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {

    if (newItem == item1Child) {
        System.out.println("MX selected");
        // do whatever you need here....
    }

});
```

Comment: thank you for example. how to i change like this-> when user select(let say MX) the method getrightPane() should be executed right next to tree. but when some other item is selected no method (only tree) should be visible on output. this is how i want, i am confused how use method like that.

Comment: @Keyur Bhanderi Thank you so much.